# A function $f$ is defined on all $\mathbb R$, and is continuous there, with finite limits at infinity. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: calculus

A function $f$ is defined on all $\mathbb R$, and is continuous there, with finite limits at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Any assistance would be much appriciated!

Comment: Hint: Consider the proof about being uniformly continuous on a compact interval. Since the limits at infinities are finite what does this tell you about the min and max of f? And the difference of the min and max?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ is not uniformly continuous. Then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and two sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ such that $|x_n-y_n|\rightarrow 0$ and $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|>\epsilon$.

If $(x_n)$ is bounded, then it has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ tends to a finite limit $x$. Then $y_{n_k}\rightarrow x$. Thus $f(x_{n_k})\rightarrow f(x)$ and $f(y_{n_k})\rightarrow f(x)$, then $|f(x_{n_k})-f(y_{n_k})|\rightarrow 0$, contradiction.

If $(x_n)$ is not bounded above, then it has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ tends to $+\infty$ (or $-\infty$). Suppose $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x)=a$. Then $f(x_{n_k})\rightarrow a$, and so does $f(y_{n_k})$. Thus $|f(x_{n_k})-f(y_{n_k})|\rightarrow 0$, contradiction again.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Don't worry about that: perhaps it's just someone bored. Your answer is fine, though perhaps the second case could be given a little more detail, Anyway, +1

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement. I edited it.

Comment: Unsure why I downvoted - possibly an accident. Fixed now!